# Change the Schema of a Table to Satisfy a few Contstraints

Tags: sql-server

Given Schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE Trains
    (Platform INTEGER NOT NULL,
    arrival DATE NOT NULL,
    departure DATE NOT NULL,
    TrainName CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Platform , arrival ));
```

Should make Changes to the Schema to make sure of 2 things.

```
    1. Should not allow Inserts Where arrival date is greater than departure date.
    2. There should be no overlaps on a single platform. i.e., If a Train A arrives on Platform 1 on 5th and leaves on 9th No other train should be inserted with Platform 1 Arriving between 5th and 9th.
```

Need to implement Constraints to address the above 2 conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1- You need a check constraints

```
ALTER TABLE Trains
ADD CONSTRAINT check1t CHECK (arrival <= departure);
```

## 2- You need a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER IU_Trains
ON Trains
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF exists (select * from Trains where [Platform] = inserted.Platform and arrival between inserted.arrival and inserted.dparture)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('You cannot do this :)', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK;
    END
END;
```